# Is there an AMP function equavlent to amp-analytics for Bing Universal Event Tracking?

Tags: javascript, bing, amp-analytics

I am attempting to track Bing Ad events using the Bing Universal Event Tracking code inside a Google Amp ready webpage. The Bing solution is to use a javascript function. This is similar to the solution used to track Google Adwords events for pages that are not AMP ready.

Javascript is not supported by AMP. To track Google Adwords in an AMP ready page, AMP uses a special function "amp-analytics". Is there an AMP function equivalent to amp-analytics for Bing Universal Event Tracking?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use amp-pixel
It works for facebook. But for bing, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I discussed this with Bing support. Bing has several methods for inserting a universal event tracker (UET). The method compatible with Google AMP is to use an image UET. The link for the image UET is found in the Bing account.

The Bing UET image link is placed inside a standard amp-image specification. The height and width are set to zero. The CSS display for the element is set to 'none'.

This solution does not affect Google tracking.

Comment: This is no longer shown in the interface...it only offers javascript tagging now